# Using 3rd party jquery plugins in Apostrophe cms

Tags: node.js, apostrophe-cms

In my Apostrophe cms I have a portion in the header like this (in the outerLayout.html file):

```
<div id="sticky-header">
...
</div>
```

In the footer I have done the following:

```
<script src="/thirdparty/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/thirdparty/sticky/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
```

I understand that apostrophe somehow includes jQuery, but if I do not include it myself I get an error in the console:

```
jquery.sticky.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at jquery.sticky.js:22
at jquery.sticky.js:24
```

I also have the following in one of the always.js files

```
$("#sticky-header").sticky({
    topSpacing:0,
    zIndex:1000
});
```

And that generates the error:

```
always.js:109 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sticky is not a function
at always.js:109
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the reason you need to push your own copy of jQuery is that including files from `outerLayout` is running front-end javascript OUTSIDE of Apostrophe's front-end asset pipeline.

To include your 3rd party / custom javascript INSIDE Apostrophe's asset pipeline (which is recommended and where jQuery is initially run) you need to push the javascript files from an Apostrophe module.

The quickest path forward is to push the asset from the `apostrophe-assets` module which should already be in your project.

in `app.js`

```
...
'apostrophe-assets': {
      scripts: [
        {
          name: 'yourFile'
        }
      ]
    },
...
```

This will load `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/yourFile.js`

More on pushing assets to the browser here http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets.html

Down the road you may want to organize front-end assets by their appropriate module instead of pushing them all in a heap, this would be a good reference 
http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html#adding-a-java-script-widget-player-on-the-browser-side

Also, what you can expect to be there when you do push javascript
http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html#what-39-s-available-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot Stuart - that definitely pushed me in the right direction :)

However what I ended up doing to make it work was to first put the files in `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/public/js/` like you suggested, and then edit the `lib/modules/apostrophe-assets/index.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    stylesheets: [
        {
            name: 'site'
        }
    ],
    scripts: [
        {
            name: 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min'
        },
        {
            name: 'sticky/jquery.sticky'
        },
        {
            name: 'scrollto/jquery.scrollTo.min'
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Sure, you're adding the same configuration to the module in a different place.

Comment: I saw that was how it was done in the example code that was generated by the CLI when creating the application. Just getting started with Apostrophe so great to learn the different ways to do things :)